# Sort File using Shell Command

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, sed, awk

I have the data look like this

```
$ cat file
(71149, 3079, 68070, 0.0433) Alex
(51135, 2881, 48254, 0.0563) Brandon
(27231, 7105, 20126, 0.2609) Chad
(8365, 3634, 4731, 0.4344) Daniel
(7490, 7346, 144, 0.9808) Eliz
(6841, 3917, 2924, 0.5726) Frank
(6740, 7393, -653, 1.0969) Gates
(5084, 500, 4584, 0.0983) Harry
(5044, 3913, 1131, 0.7758) Ian
(4760, 699, 4061, 0.1468) Jack
....
```

I want to sort the content by the last element in the bracket, how can i do it in command line.

```
$ cat file | ... magic ... 
(6740, 7393, -653, 1.0969) Gates
(7490, 7346, 144, 0.9808) Eliz
(5044, 3913, 1131, 0.7758) Ian
(6841, 3917, 2924, 0.5726) Frank
(8365, 3634, 4731, 0.4344) Daniel
(27231, 7105, 20126, 0.2609) Chad
(4760, 699, 4061, 0.1468) Jack
(5084, 500, 4584, 0.0983) Harry
(51135, 2881, 48254, 0.0563) Brandon
(71149, 3079, 68070, 0.0433) Alex
....
```

I succeeded in sorting the number but I don't know how to print the whole line in awk.

```
$cat file | sed 's/)//g' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $4}' | sort -r
5.1246
4.3936
2.7811
2.5
1.9
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
kent$  sort  -k4nr file
(6740, 7393, -653, 1.0969) Gates
(7490, 7346, 144, 0.9808) Eliz
(5044, 3913, 1131, 0.7758) Ian
(6841, 3917, 2924, 0.5726) Frank
(8365, 3634, 4731, 0.4344) Daniel
(27231, 7105, 20126, 0.2609) Chad
(4760, 699, 4061, 0.1468) Jack
(5084, 500, 4584, 0.0983) Harry
(51135, 2881, 48254, 0.0563) Brandon
(71149, 3079, 68070, 0.0433) Alex
```

Comment: the default field separator should be white space right? then the fourth element is actually "1.0969)" which include the brackets... you can still sort even with weird characters in the field?

Comment: @B.Mr.W. so long as there are *always* 4 decimal places in that column it *should* work fine.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Well a more consistent sort would be `cat file | tr -d '(),' | sort -k4nr` if you're more interested in simply viewing the results and the particular output formatting isn't important.